# Trying to generate SVG text in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, svg

I'm making a symbol generator in C# using [this](http://vvvv.github.io/SVG/api/Svg.html) SVG library. As I try to include text like this:

```
        private void buttonDraw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        document(); //function to prepare the document and canvas.

        SvgUnitCollection pin1 = new SvgUnitCollection()
        {0,50};
        
        SvgText hello = new SvgText();
        hello.Text = "Hello World";
        hello.X = pin1;
        hello.Y = pin1;

        SvgGroup.myGroup.Children.Add(hello);// Adding elements to the canvas.

        draw(); //Function to draw into an image box.
    }
```

I get this:

[image]

Any help to correct this issue and explanation in why does this happen, is very appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys. After all, the problem was that I put two svg units in the collection and I needed  two separate collections, like this:

```
SvgUnitCollection textX = new SvgUnitCollection()
        { 60};

        SvgUnitCollection textY = new SvgUnitCollection()
        { 85};

        SvgUnitCollection center= new SvgUnitCollection()
        { 14};
     
        SvgText hello= new SvgText();
        hello.Text = "Hello world"
        hello.X = textX;
        hello.Y = textY;
        hello.Dx = center;//align the text to your canvas as you want.
        hello.FontSize = 27;
```

It  seems kind of redundant for me but it works with this library. Thank you again. (Not sarcasm, just not native english speaker)